# uibutton not allowing uiscrollview to scroll

Tags: iphone

hi i have uiscrollview and uipage control and in uiscrollview i have buttons (custom buttons)

and the coading is as follows

```
bodyView                                            = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,
                                                                                                    0,
                                                                                                    320,
                                                                                                    415)];
bodyView.userInteractionEnabled                     = YES;
bodyView.pagingEnabled                              = YES;  
bodyView.contentSize                                = CGSizeMake(640,self.bodyView.frame.size.height);
bodyView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator             = NO;
bodyView.scrollEnabled                              = YES;
bodyView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator               = NO;
bodyView.scrollsToTop                               = NO;
bodyView.delegate                                   = self;
bodyView.canCancelContentTouches                    = NO;
bodyView.delaysContentTouches                       = NO;

[self.view addSubview:self.bodyView];

pageControl=[[UIPageControl alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,425,320,10)];
pageControl.numberOfPages = kNumberOfPages;
pageControl.currentPage = 0;
pageControl.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
pageControl.multipleTouchEnabled=YES;

[pageControl addTarget:self action:@selector(changePageNavigation) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[pageControl addTarget:self action:@selector(changePageNavigation) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[self.view addSubview:pageControl]; 

[self.view bringSubviewToFront:bodyView];

- (void)createIcons{


    buttonCustom = [self createDynamicCustomButtons:CGRectMake(12, 103, 65, 65) 
                                              image:[UIImage imageFromPath:TKBUNDLE(@"Images.bundle/Images/HomeScreen/pharmacy.png")] 
                                                tag:1];
    [bodyView addSubview:buttonCustom];

    labelCustom = [self createDynamicCustomLabels:CGRectMake(12,185, 80, 13) 
                                             text:NSLocalizedString(@"pharmacyTitle",nil)];
    [bodyView addSubview:labelCustom];

    buttonCustom = [self createDynamicCustomButtons:CGRectMake(120, 103, 65, 65) 
                                              image:[UIImage imageFromPath:TKBUNDLE(@"Images.bundle/Images/HomeScreen/photo.png")] 
                                                tag:2];
    [bodyView addSubview:buttonCustom];

    labelCustom = [self createDynamicCustomLabels:CGRectMake(116, 185,80, 13) 
                                             text:NSLocalizedString(@"photo Title",nil)];
    [bodyView addSubview:labelCustom];

    buttonCustom = [self createDynamicCustomButtons:CGRectMake(227, 103, 65, 65) 
                                              image:[UIImage imageFromPath:TKBUNDLE(@"Images.bundle/Images/HomeScreen/store_locator.png")] 
                                                tag:3];
    [bodyView addSubview:buttonCustom];

    labelCustom = [self createDynamicCustomLabels:CGRectMake(225, 185, 80, 13) 
                                             text:NSLocalizedString(@"StoreTitle",nil)];
    [bodyView addSubview:labelCustom];

    buttonCustom = [self createDynamicCustomButtons:CGRectMake(12, 208, 65, 65) 
                                              image:[UIImage imageFromPath:TKBUNDLE(@"Images.bundle/Images/HomeScreen/coupons.png")] 
                                                tag:12];
    [bodyView addSubview:buttonCustom];

    labelCustom = [self createDynamicCustomLabels:CGRectMake(23, 290, 60, 13) 
                                             text:NSLocalizedString(@"couponsTitle",nil)];
    [bodyView addSubview:labelCustom];  

    buttonCustom = [self createDynamicCustomButtons:CGRectMake(120, 208, 65, 65) 
                                              image:[UIImage imageFromPath:TKBUNDLE(@"Images.bundle/Images/HomeScreen/refill_by_scan.png")]
                                                tag:6];
    [bodyView addSubview:buttonCustom];

    labelCustom = [self createDynamicCustomLabels:CGRectMake(116, 290, 89, 13) 
                                             text:NSLocalizedString(@"Refill Title",nil)];
    [bodyView addSubview:labelCustom];      

    //buttonCustom = [self createDynamicCustomButtons:CGRectMake(224, 220, 65, 65) 
    //                                        image:[UIImage imageFromPath:TKBUNDLE(@"Images.bundle/Images/HomeScreen/65x65_weekly_ad.png")] 
    buttonCustom = [self createDynamicCustomButtons:CGRectMake(227, 208, 65, 62) 
                                              image:[UIImage imageFromPath:TKBUNDLE(@"Images.bundle/Images/HomeScreen/multi_scan.png")] 
                                                tag:7];
    [bodyView addSubview:buttonCustom];

    labelCustom = [self createDynamicCustomLabels:CGRectMake(225, 290, 86, 13) 
                                             text:NSLocalizedString(@"scanner",nil)];
    [bodyView addSubview:labelCustom];  



    buttonCustom = [self createDynamicCustomButtons:  CGRectMake(12, 313, 65, 65)
                                              image:[UIImage imageFromPath:TKBUNDLE(@"Images.bundle/Images/HomeScreen/shopping_list.png")] 
                                                tag:9];
    [bodyView addSubview:buttonCustom];

    labelCustom = [self createDynamicCustomLabels:CGRectMake(15,395, 75, 13) 
                                             text:NSLocalizedString(@"ShoppinglistTitle",nil)];
    [bodyView addSubview:labelCustom];


    buttonCustom = [self createDynamicCustomButtons:CGRectMake(120, 313, 65, 65) 
                                              image:[UIImage imageFromPath:TKBUNDLE(@"Images.bundle/Images/HomeScreen/weekly_ad.png")] 
                                                tag:8];
    [bodyView addSubview:buttonCustom];

    labelCustom = [self createDynamicCustomLabels: CGRectMake(120,395, 80, 13)
                                             text:NSLocalizedString(@"Weeklyads title",nil)];
    [bodyView addSubview:labelCustom];



    buttonCustom = [self createDynamicCustomButtons:CGRectMake(227, 313, 65, 65) 
                                              image:[UIImage imageFromPath:TKBUNDLE(@"Images.bundle/Images/HomeScreen/gift_finder.png")] 
                                                tag:nil];
    [bodyView addSubview:buttonCustom];

    labelCustom = [self createDynamicCustomLabels:CGRectMake(237, 395, 60, 13) 
                                             text:NSLocalizedString(@"giftFinder",nil)];
    [bodyView addSubview:labelCustom];


    buttonCustom = [self createDynamicCustomButtons:CGRectMake(333, 103, 65, 65) 
                                              image:[UIImage imageFromPath:TKBUNDLE(@"Images.bundle/Images/HomeScreen/shop.png")] 
                                                tag:4];
    [bodyView addSubview:buttonCustom];

    labelCustom = [self createDynamicCustomLabels:CGRectMake(344, 185, 60, 13) 
                                             text:NSLocalizedString(@"shop",nil)];
    [bodyView addSubview:labelCustom];


    buttonCustom = [self createDynamicCustomButtons:CGRectMake(440, 103, 65, 65) 
                                              image:[UIImage imageFromPath:TKBUNDLE(@"Images.bundle/Images/HomeScreen/find_a_clinic.png")] 
                                                tag:11];
    [bodyView addSubview:buttonCustom];

    labelCustom = [self createDynamicCustomLabels:CGRectMake(439, 185,80, 13) 
                                             text:NSLocalizedString(@"clinicTitle",nil)];
    [bodyView addSubview:labelCustom];




    buttonCustom = [self createDynamicCustomButtons:CGRectMake(547, 103, 65, 65) 
                                              image:[UIImage imageFromPath:TKBUNDLE(@"Images.bundle/Images/HomeScreen/settings.png")] 
                                                tag:10];
    [bodyView addSubview:buttonCustom];

    labelCustom = [self createDynamicCustomLabels:CGRectMake(558, 185, 60, 14) 
                                             text:NSLocalizedString(@"settingsTitle",nil)];
    [bodyView addSubview:labelCustom];


}


//Begin - To create a icon's custom button ***Sujya***
-(UIButtonCustom *)createDynamicCustomButtons:(CGRect)frame image:(UIImage *)buttonImage tag:(int)tagValue 
{
    UIButtonCustom *customIconButton            = [UIButtonCustom buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [customIconButton retain];
    //customIconButton.buttonType =UIButtonTypeCustom;
    [customIconButton setImage:buttonImage 
                      forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [customIconButton addTarget:self 
                         action:@selector(btnIconClicked:) 
               forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [customIconButton setTag:tagValue];
    frame.size.width=buttonImage.size.width;
    frame.size.height=buttonImage.size.height;

    [customIconButton setFrame:frame];
    return customIconButton;
}
```

i am able to scroll the view with out tapping on the button but on touching the button and i try to scroll but un able to scroll the view

can any one please tell me how to scroll on touching the buttton

Comment: Please edit your question properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i have understood correctly, you want to scroll the scrollView by tapping a UIButton.
UIScrollView has a method
`scrollRectToVisible:animated:` to scroll programmatically your scrollView.

You can try this:

```
-(IBAction)switchToPG2{
    CGRect frame = self.scrollView.frame;
    frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * 1;//or the index of the page that you want
    self.pageControl.currentPage=1;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    [self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];
}
```

Hope this helps.